# Searching for users and populating a form with AJAX and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, autocomplete

I am looking to populate a registration form with previous registrant data.
Currently, I created a search field where you start typing a last name and a list of buttons appears showing names and birthdays using Ajax, Jquery and PHP (from a MySQL db).

I want it so that you then click on the correct name and it populates the form fields.

I was looking for advice on whether I should have the buttons (when clicked) make a new Ajax call to a PHP search file, passing the ID for that registrant, or if I should simply store all of the data I need during the first Ajax call and then just pass that info to my form fields when the button it clicked.

Is there an advantage to doing it one way or the other?

If a thousand names came up in the search, storing all the data take a while, but if it were only a small number of returned names would it be a big deal?

Further, I can clearly figure out how I would make the second Ajax search work, but I am not clear on the best way to store the info if I did it on the first call.  (Store in an Array?  Can the JSON data just be parsed directly - if so, I can't conceive "were it would live" while a button is waiting to be clicked.

Here is my current code (mostly plucked from the Internet) that is generating my buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//
  $("#searchbox").keyup(function(e){
    var q = "data=" + $("#searchbox").val();
    var sLength = q.length;
    if (sLength > 7){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "autoLookup.php?" + q,
        success:
    function(data) {
      $("#searchResult").empty();
      $("#searchButtonHeader").empty();
      $("#searchButtonHeader").append("Results for <b>" + q + "</b>");

      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        $("#searchResult").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary regName' name='" + item.uId + "'>" + item.firstname + " " + item.lastname + " (" + item.city + ", " + item.state + " " + item.dobf + ") </button>");
        //storeVals
        qArray = 

      });
    }
  })
}//if
else {
    $("#searchResult").empty();
    }
```

});

Thanks for the input!!!

J

adding this info:

Hi Jakub, thank you for your help...this is my "autolookup.php" file:

```
$key = $_GET['data'];
    $return_arr = array();

    //search older roster for runner data
    $query =("SELECT * FROM roster2015done WHERE lastname LIKE '{$key}%' ORDER BY lastname, firstname, dob");

    //echo $query . "<br><br>";
    if ($key != "") {
        $result = SQL($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          $array['uId'] = $row['Id'];
          $array['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
          $array['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
          $array['city'] = $row['city'] ;
          $array['state'] = $row['state'];
          $array['dob'] = $row['dob'];
          $array['dobf'] = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row['dob'])); //dob formatted for diaplay
          $array['addr1'] = $row['addr1'];
          $array['addr2'] = $row['addr2'];
          $array['email'] = $row['email'] ;
          $array['phone'] = $row['phone'];

        array_push($return_arr, $array);
        }
        echo json_encode($return_arr);
    }else{
        $return_arr = "";
        echo json_encode($return_arr); //send empty array if search box is emptied. (belt and suspenders: js is doing this already)
        }
```

As you can see, I have PHP pulling the data I want from the db and adding it to the array and then JSON encoding.  So when my "buttons" are being created back on my html page, though I am only displaying first name, last name, city and dob, I am actually bring over the other fields I would ultimately want to populate the form as well (I had added this  - then came up with my question as to whether this was a good idea or not).

What I am unsure about is that, say I return 10 results.  I am displaying 10 buttons (each time it iterates over "item", it creates the buttons), but if I then want to be able to click on the correct button and have that person's info populate the form, is that data still available to be "searched" and used?  And if so, where is it?  Is the JSON array (or Object - not sure the right term for it) still "available" to be searched / parsed?  Or should I also be storing the info in a new multi-dimensional array or something that I can then access?  (I realized that seems kind of redundant if I already have a JSON object that is searchable - but do I?)

Thanks, J

HERE is the code I ended up using to populate the form on button click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

var data;

```
  $("#searchbox").keyup(function(e){
    var q = "data=" + $("#searchbox").val();
    var sLength = q.length;
    if (sLength > 7){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "autoLookup.php?" + q,
        success:
    function(data) {
        var results = data; **//ADDED THIS BECUASE USING data var below didn't work.**
      $("#searchResult").empty();
      $("#searchButtonHeader").empty();
      $("#searchButtonHeader").append("Results for <b>" + q + "</b>");

      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        $("#searchResult").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary regName' name='" + item.uId + "'>" + item.firstname + " " + item.lastname + " (" + item.city + ", " + item.state + " " + item.dobf + ") </button>");
      });

      **//HERE IS WHAT I ADDED TO POPULATE THE FORM**

        $("#searchResult").on('click', ".regName", function(data){
        //alert($(this).attr('name'));
        var userId = $(this).attr('name');
        $.each(results, function(i,item){
            //alert(item.uId + " : " + userId);
            if (item.uId == userId){
                //alert ("Name is: " + item.firstname + item.lastname);
                $("#lastname").val(item.lastname);
                $("#firstname").val(item.firstname);
                $("#addr1").val(item.addr1);
                $("#addr2").val(item.addr2);
                $("#city").val(item.city);
                $("#state").val(item.state);
                $("#zip").val(item.zip);
                $("#email").val(item.email);
                $("#phone").val(item.phone);
                $("#dob").val(item.dob);
                $("#gender").val(item.gender);
                $("#size").val(item.size);

                //remove buttons.
                $("#searchResult").empty();
                }
            });
        });

    }
  })

}//if
else {
    $("#searchResult").empty();
    }
```

});

Comment: Look at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

on the server side (PHP) make a limitation e.g. to 10 names. If someone enters 2 letters, and can't see his name, he has to put another letter - but usually this solution is ok. In PHP return an array of JSON objects - so in JavaScript you can see returned data:

```
 data = [
     {
        firstname: "someName",
        lastname: "someLastName",
        city: "someCity",
        state: "someState",
        dobf: "someDobf"
     },
     {
        firstname: "someName2",
        lastname: "someLastName2",
        city: "someCity2",
        state: "someState2",
        dobf: "someDobf2"
     },
     {
        firstname: "someName10",
        lastname: "someLastName10",
        city: "someCity10",
        state: "someState10",
        dobf: "someDobf10"
     }];
```

you can make an onClick function:

```
 $("#searchResult").append("<button type='button' onclick = 'fillForm(" + i + ");' class='btn btn-primary regName' name='" + item.uId + "'>" + item.firstname + " " + item.lastname + " (" + item.city + ", " + item.state + " " + item.dobf + ") </button>");
```

When user clicks his name:

```
var fillForm = function(i){
   console.log(data[i]); //here you will have data for that user e.g.: data[i].firstname
   $('#yourFirstNameField').val(data[i].firstname); //fill your form
}
```

this function should be inside `data` scope.

Two more things:

1. your php code is vulnarable for sql injection
2. it is better to count the real length if the #searchbox field:

   var q = $("#searchbox").val();

   var sLength = q.length;
   if (sLength > 2){
   }

you can always do thath: `url: "autoLookup.php?data=" + q`

Comment: Hi Jakub, thank you.  I added my PHP to my original question.  (I'm fairly new to JSON-thanks for bearing with me).  Ah, I didn't think about that "data" contains the entirety of my php output. (ie JSON encoded results) -the info is "living" inside the var "data"- correct?  So I just tried to "document.write(data)" and all I see is "[object Object], [O..."  do I have to search "data" using some other function like this?  (also found on net):  `$.each(json.people.person, function(i, v) {
        if (v.name.search(new RegExp(/peter/i)) != -1) {
            alert(v.age);
            return;`

Comment: Regarding the potential for SQL injection, I normally add htmlentities() to my post/get variables for a little insurance. - I forgot to do that.

Comment: Regarding potential for SQL injection, I normally add htmlentities() to post/get vars for a little insurance-forgot to do that.

As you can see, I'm counting entered characters before making ajax call in JS - mainly to avoid having to wait for 100's of returned results after entering only 1st letter (there are a few thousand entries in the DB).  I like your idea to pass the count to my PHP, too.  Not sure why, but I wasn't able to use "data" directly in my form fill function, but I assigned its value to new var "results" and then iterated over that to fill form.  See update to my post. Thx!